# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using a thinner yoga mat?

Tags: exercise-equipment, yoga

I practice `Bikram` and have been using a 3 mm mat which is now well due for replacement.

I am wondering if it makes sense to aspire for an even thinner mat, i.e. if it is better for you to practice on a skinny mat, i.e. go for 2 mm or even less.

Comment: What's good and what's bad about a skinnier mat?

Comment: that was my question, @Kate

Comment: Okay, cool :) I suggested an edit to your title, then. That should help get you better answers.

Comment: Related (not duplicate though): [What should I look for in a fitness exercise mat?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/9684/3941)

Comment: I removed the shopping request as shopping questions are off topic on the site (check the [faq]). If you are unhappy with the changes, feel free to revert them or edit again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Purely a 'by experience' answer here, having tried both:

**Advantages of a thinner mat:**

- More sturdy foundation for balancing
- Far less bulky when rolled up for transport/storage
- Dries quicker from sweat/moisture (especially important in Bikram)

**Advantages of a thicker mat:**

- Knee cushioning when kneeling
- Tops of the feet cushioning when sitting on your heels
- Head cushioning when doing headstands

Answer (score 3):

The thickness of your yoga mat has a lot to do with how comfortable it is — too thin, and your knee may get banged up during crescent lunge. The tradeoff is that thick yoga mats (some as thick as 1/4 inch) can make it harder for you to feel a strong connection to the floor, making you more wobbly. Otherwise, it really just depends on whether you want a bulky mat to be carrying around.