# Prevent Injuries At Home Gym on Carpet

Tags: exercise, injury, injury-prevention, home-exercise, p90x

I have started some exercise programs at home such as P90X and Insanity.  However, I have found that working out on my carpet has proven to be difficult in a number of ways.  For example, when jumping around, I will often get carpet burn injuries on my feet.  When doing the various forms of pushups I, again, will sustain burns to my hands.  These can become really painful and have limited my success in these programs.  What are some methods that I can use to help prevent related injuries when working out at home and on a carpeted surface?  Additionally, I sweat a lot during these programs and am worried if the carpet my start to take on a smell or become more difficult to clean.  Are there any suggestions for this as well?

Comment: You can get flex tiles (interlocking rubber squares) for pretty cheap. If you need it to come up quickly or on a regular basis you might want to look at some other type of flooring. You could also consider shoes and thin gloves. XD

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Do you have any leads or tips on what kind of tiles or where to buy them from?  I did not really want to wear shoes on the carpet and possibly wear the carpet out early.

Comment: Just do a Google search (or Bing, etc.) for Rubber Gym Floors. There are so many to choose from. From really thick and solid, to the ones that pools use with holes to keep swimmers from slipping on the deck.

Answer (score 1):

I did exercise on carpet before, and never had problems with skin-burns, but using an exercise mat should help with your problems.

I bought a mat myself a few months ago - mostly because of sweating, as the floor in my room is some sort of PVC. It is easier on the hands now, and the strange feeling when touching the floor with wet skin disappears, too.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  What kind of mat did you buy?  Where did you purchase it from?

Comment: I think any mat will do to help with your problems, I asked [how to chose a mat in another question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/9684/3941) before.

Comment: Here is an interesting link that I found while doing further research on this topic:  http://www.wesellmats.com/blog/what-makes-a-good-exercise-mat-for-p90x/